# Nginx running Ghost: add public www location?

Tags: nginx, webserver, ghost-blog

I'm trying to upload a bunch of html and image files to my Nginx webserver which is running Ghost (the blogging platform) lets call it `ghost-blog.com`. Ghost runs perfectly fine, but additionaly I want serve other files and folders under the same domain e.g. `ghost-blog.com/text.html` and `ghost-blog.com/subfolder/index.html`.

After spending some time googling for an answer it seems I've bumped into something "new". I am aware I need to make changes to the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file. What I don't know is what to add/edit so that

1. I create a `/some/random/public` folder public
2. This does not conflict with Ghost which is already serving content, specially the default `index index.html index.htm` files.

My current `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` config file looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.ghost-blog.com;
  rewrite ^/(.*) http://ghost-blog.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
root /usr/share/nginx/www;
index index.html index.htm;

server_name localhost;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;       
  }

location /doc/ {
    alias /usr/share/doc/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
  }
}
```

Any suggestions on how I could go around creating a `/public` folder serving other files and sub-folders?

Comment: I don't understand what you want exactly, do u want to create a new folder, or a new website?, if you want to create just a normal folder, it should already work, because of the `$uri/` inside your `try_files`

Comment: I want serve other files and folders under the same domain `ghost-blog.com/text.html` and be able to create subfolders `ghost-blog.com/subfolder/index.html`.

Comment: did you try doing that? what error do you get when trying to access it.

Comment: "what error do you get when trying to access it": 404

Comment: can't you upload the files and try accessing them, in the any folder you have, because right now I think your configuration should work just fine.

Comment: Please see discussion in the Answer below, all of this has already been discussed.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.ghost-blog.com/subfolder;
  rewrite ^/(.*) http://ghost-blog.com/subfolder/$1 permanent;
}

server {
root /usr/share/nginx/www/NEWSITEFOLDER;
index index.html index.htm;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;       
  }

location /doc/ {
    alias /usr/share/doc/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
  }
}
```

then in ssh you need to make this directory to run the new ghost blog from

```
  /usr/share/nginx/www/NEWSITEFOLDER;
```

so run command

```
  mkdir /usr/share/nginx/www/NEWSITEFOLDER;
```

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the quick response. I've added/edited `root /usr/share/nginx/www/NEWSITEFOLDER;` uploaded a test file, restarted Nginx, but get a 404. Any other suggestions?

Comment: is that the entire nginx config or is there more?

Comment: that's the entire configuration, and yes, the folder was created i.e. `NEWSITEFOLDER ` folder created, `NEWSITEFOLDER` added to `default`config file, html files uploaded to `NEWSITEFOLDER`

Comment: is the index file of the /subfolder an index.html or other extension, if your going to www.ghost-blog.com/subfolder and the index is a php file a 404error will happen as the index file is set to a .html, otherwise this rewrite rule 
     server_name www.ghost-blog.com/;
     rewrite ^/(.*) http://ghost-blog.com/$1 permanent;
might be rewriting everything from /* including your new site if thats the casue try running it from a subdomain

Comment: the file is not an `index.html` file, but `othertext.html`. I need to serve several non-index.html files via this domain, both from `ghost-blog.com/` and `ghost-blog.com/NEWSITEFOLDER`

Comment: well if your trying to go to ghost-blog.com/subfolder with no file name and extension nginx wont pick a default file for you throwing a 404 error

can i see the .htaccess from your "ghost-blog.com" domain

Comment: there is no .htaccess (Apache), it's running nginx hence the `default` config file having www to no-www rewrite.

also, when going to `ghost-blog.com/` and `ghost-blog.com/NEWSITEFOLDER`I type in the entire url, including the file name+extension, that shouldn't be throwing a 404.